# Mover elementos de una pila

Tags: python, pilas, spyder

Necesito un método `final` que no recibe ningún parámetro y se limita a mover el primer nodo de la lista al final. Observa que se trata de mover el nodo y NO simplemente desencolarlo y encolarlo de nuevo. Es decir, que no debes llamar a los métodos `enqueue` ni `dequeue` ni al constructor de la clase `Node` en ningún momento. En el caso de aplicar este método a una lista vacía, el método no hará nada.

Y un método `girar` que recibe como argumento un número entero no negativo y simplemente aplica el método `final` ese número de veces.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

class LinkedQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None
        self._last = None
        self._size = 0

    def enqueue(self,value):
        newnode = Node(value)
        if self._head is None:
            self._head = newnode
        else:
            self._last.next = newnode
        self._last = newnode
        self._size += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise IndexError("dequeue from empty queue")
        returned = self._head.value
        self._head = self._head.next
        if self._head is None:
            self._last = None
        self._size -= 1
        return returned
```

```
def final(self):
    self._head = None
    self._last = None
    nuevo = Nodo(x)
    if self.ultimo:
        self._last.prox = nuevo
        self._last = nuevo
    else:
        self._head = nuevo
        self._last = nuevo

def girar(self, numero): 
    if numero >= 0 : 
        alfinal (numero)
```

Comment: No se cómo puedo mover un nodo sin necesidad de desencolar y encolar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empiezas tu método muy mal:

```
self._head = None
self._last = None
nuevo = Nodo(x)
```

Primero asignas `None` a `self._head` y `self._last`, eso deja la lista totalmente inservible ya que deja de poder recorrerse. Además, creas una nueva instancia de `Nodo`, cuando lo que necesitas no es crear un Nodo, sino solo moverlo de sitio.

La secuencia sería:

1. Al último nodo actual de a lista, cuyo atributo `next` será `None`, le asignamos como valor de dicho atributo una referencia al primer nodo de la lista (el que se va a desplazar)
2. Hacemos que le último nodo de la lista sea el que ahora es el primero, asignando a `self._last` el nodo al que apunta ahora `self._head`.
3. Solo queda asignar a `self.head` el que antes era el segundo nodo de la lista, `self._head.next`.

---

```
    def final(self):
        if self._size < 2:
            return
        self._last.next = self._last = self._head
        self._head = self._head.next
        self._last.next = None
```

El método `girar` es trivial, solo necesitas un ciclo que itere `n` veces y en cada iteración llamar a `self.final`:

```
    def girar(self, numero): 
        for _ in range(numero): 
            self.final()
```

La clase con los métodos agregados, además de la implementación de `__str__` para facilitar la visualización del contenido de la lista:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

class LinkedQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None
        self._last = None
        self._size = 0

    def enqueue(self,value):
        newnode = Node(value)
        if self._head is None:
            self._head = newnode
        else:
            self._last.next = newnode
        self._last = newnode
        self._size += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise IndexError("dequeue from empty queue")
        returned = self._head.value
        self._head = self._head.next
        if self._head is None:
            self._last = None
        self._size -= 1
        return returned

    def final(self):
        if self._size < 2:
            return
        self._last.next = self._last = self._head
        self._head = self._head.next
        self._last.next = None

    def girar(self, numero): 
        for _ in range(numero): 
            self.final()

    def __str__(self):
        values = []
        node = self._head
        for _ in range(self._size):
            values.append(str(node.value))
            node = node.next
        return f'[{" <- ".join(values)}]'
```

> ```
> >>> que = LinkedQueue()
> >>> que.enqueue(1)
> >>> que.enqueue(2)
> >>> que.enqueue(3)
> >>> que.enqueue(4)
>
> >>> print(que)
> [1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4]
>
> >>> que.final()
> >>> print(que)
> [2 <- 3 <- 4 <- 1]
>
>
> >>> que.girar(2)
> >>> print(que)
> [4 <- 1 <- 2 <- 3]
> ```